# How to invoke enum from a header file?

Tags: c++, enums

I am working on a block of codes and I have a enum declaration which is in TTTEnum.h file:

```
 #ifndef TTTEnum
 #define TTTEnum

 enum class Winner
 {
  Empty,
  Computer,
  Player
 };
 #endif
```

I have another header file which is TTT.h and I try to put all my prototypes of my functions which seems like:

```
 #ifndef TTT_H_INCLUDED
 #define TTT_H_INCLUDED

 #include "TTTEnum.h"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cmath>

 using namespace std;


 TTTEnum::Winner gameSquares[] = { Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, 
 Empty, Empty, Empty,Empty, Empty };
 class TTT
 {
  public:

  int movesMade = 0;

  void HowTo();
  void PlayerTurn();
  bool FirstGo();
  int GetPossibleMoves(int possible_index[9], Winner who, const Winner *const board = gameSquares);
  int GetWinIndex(const Winner who);
  void ComputerTurn();
  void PrintBoard();

  };
  #endif
```

When I compile these codes I get 8-9 lines of errors that says 'Empty' was not declared in this scope. I have been checking other enum problems and I see that enum is really tricky when you try to invoke it to other file. Is there any solution that is going to help me?

Comment: What's up with `TTTEnum::Winner`? I don't see a `TTTEnum` namespace.

Comment: Where exactly do I have to use TTTEnum namespace? In TTTEnum.h file or In TTT.h? I thought TTTEnum::Winner would be enough to invoke. Thanks your time Jonathon Reinhart

Comment: `TTTEnum`  is just a preprocessor macro defined in your header file, acting as an [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). It has nothing to do with C++ namespaces, like you're trying to use it as when you say `TTTEnum::Winner`. What's actually happening is `TTTEnum` is expanded to an empty string, and you're left with `::Winner` (global namespace).

Comment: So I will remove TTTEnum:: declaration from TTTEnum::Winner? And instead of saying enum class Winner, I will change to enum namespace?

Comment: Jonathon Reinhart- Would you mind giving me another declaration. I have been trying to figure this out for hours. It will blow my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scope the name `Empty` with `Winner` if you are using `enum class`, as per http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html

i.e `Winner::Empty` rather than just `Empty` should work.

Comment: Thank you Karthik. Give me a sec to go over the link you have posted!

Comment: sTTTEnum::Winner gameSquares[] = { Winner::Empty, Winner::Empty, Winner::Empty, Winner::Empty, Winner::Empty, Winner::Empty, Winner::Empty,Winner::Empty, Winner::Empty };

Comment: @tuygun Drop the `TTTEnum::`. That's incorrect, as [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775227/how-to-invoke-enum-from-a-header-file#comment36562183_23775227) explains.